# Why the value of data.route_list is not changing when the state of routes is changed in react upon useEffect call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function App(props) {

  
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState({ 
    login_type: 70,
    roleId: "1223",
    route_list:routes
    });

  console.log(data.route_list)
  useEffect(() => {
    setRoutes(["hello", 2, 3, 3])
  },[])


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when the useEffect will be called after initial rendering it will update the routes array by calling setRoutes funtion. so for first time console will print [](empty array) but after updating the routes array rendering will happen again so then why it is printing empty array again instead of array that is updated??

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `route_list` with empty array. Even though you updated route state, you have to explicitly tell react to update the data state. You can add another useEffect with routes as dependency and then update data

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData({
      ...data
      route_list: routes
    });
  }, [routes]);
```

Comment: But when state changes in react, it will also update the particulars who have used this state?